# Full-text search in PDO using parameters

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, pdo

I am trying to do a **full text** search using PDO with a parameter.

If I use the sql query with a constant variable, the select works, and it returns the correct list from the MySQL database.

But the code I have to select on a parameter does not return anything.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $conn  = new PDO ("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
 $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

 $val = $_REQUEST['val'];
 $sth = $conn ->prepare('SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE MATCH (First, Last) AGAINST (:val IN BOOLEAN MODE');

 $sth->execute(array(':val' => $val));
 $friends = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $json=json_encode($friends);
 echo $json;
 ?>
```

From my app I call the above function as follows:

```
 smUID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myServerName.co.uk/searchQuery.php?val=%@", searchString];
 dataSMURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:smUID]];
 smUIDResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataSMURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I don't think my PDO is right as it is not returning any values, but I can't see what is wrong or what else it needs.

Comment: No, no errors and nothing is returned...